# Pyspark - saveAsTable - How to Insert new data to existing table?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**How to Insert new data to existing table???**

I'm trying to insert new data to existing table using pyspark.

This is my program

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, DataFrameWriter

sc = SparkContext("local[*]", "SPARK-SQL")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.json("people.json")
df.registerTempTable("people")

# Show old data
result = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from people")
result.show()

# Create new data
new_data = [{"name": "Phan", "age": 22}]
df_new_data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(new_data)
# Save data to table 'people'
df_new_data.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("people")

# Show new data
result = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from people")
result.show()
```

After I run it. Data in table "people" can not be changed.

```
Old data
+---+--------+
|age|    name|
+---+--------+
| 30| Michael|
| 30|    Andy|
| 19|  Justin|
| 21|PhanHien|
+---+--------+
New data
+---+--------+                                                                  
|age|    name|
+---+--------+
| 30| Michael|
| 30|    Andy|
| 19|  Justin|
| 21|PhanHien|
+---+--------+
```

Please help me to change data in table!!!
Thank you!

Comment: Did you manage to find answer for this??

Answer (score 3):

I tried to saveAsTable with a table name **does not exist**.

```
df_new_data.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("people1")

# Show new data
result = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from people1")
result.show()
```

It worked. And I can see new data in table **"people1"**

```
+---+----+
|age|name|
+---+----+
|22 |Phan|
+---+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> df_new_data.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("people")
```

The above code writes **people** table in **default database** in hive.

So if you want to see the data from hive table you need to create **HiveContext** then view results from **hive table** instead of temporary table.

```
>>> hc=HiveContext(sc)
>>> hc.sql("select * from default.people").show(100,False)
```

> **UPDATE:**

Append new data to **temporary table**:

```
>>> df1=df
>>> df2=df.unionAll(df1)
>>> df2.registerTempTable("people")
>>> sqlContext.sql("select * from people").show(100,False)
```

Comment: I made a mistake when copy my program to Stack Overflow. 
Actually, my program same as you said. But it is not working!

Comment: So, How can I append new data to existing temporary table?

Comment: Did you figure this out??